# teradata betq assigning variable from query

Tags: sql, unix, teradata

I have a BTEQ script that has a parametrized date value. The date value is set based on another select query. How can I execute the select query to read the date and use in the BTEQ script
Example

## Read the max(order_date) from table1

select max(order_date) as max_order_date
from table1

## Use the max_order_date in the BTEQ

select max_order_date as report_run_dt, ....
from table2
...

How can I read the max_order_paramter and store it as date paamter to be passed to BTEQ

Comment: If you need that parameter only in a single Select you can simply embed it: `select (select max(order_date) from table1) as report_run_dt, .... from table2 ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create volatile table with one column, insert variable. so volatile table will be one column, one row. Use it now with your select query.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE maxdt
AS 
select max(order_date) as max_order_date from table1
WITH DATA;



select maxdt.max_order_date as report_run_dt, .... 
from table2 cross join maxdt;
```